# AutoMapper inherited mapping not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

I have three business objects:

```
public abstract class PayCaddyEntity : IPayCaddyEntity
{
    protected PayCaddyEntity()
    {
        if (IsPopulated && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id))
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `PayCaddyEntity` basically just provides a common `Id` property and acts as a 'marker' I can use in generic constraints.

```
public abstract class PayCaddyMessage : PayCaddyEntity
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Sender { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Receiver { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeSent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeReceived { get; set; }
}

public class BetPaymentOffer: PayCaddyMessage
{        
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried mapping them to a common view model as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PayCaddyMessage, BetPaymentOfferViewModel>()
    .Include<BetPaymentOffer, BetPaymentOfferViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<BetPaymentOffer, BetPaymentOfferViewModel>();
```

and

```
var offer = new BetPaymentOffer { Sender = GetCurrentUser() };
var model = Mapper.Map<BetPaymentOfferViewModel>(offer);
```

The base class property set on the derived class is not mapped. In `model`, `Sender` is null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance changed in AutoMapper 4.0 - in order to fix a number of scenarios, the inheritance chain is calculated at config time. Call `Mapper.Configuration.Seal()` after configuration, or even better, use `Mapper.Initialize()` instead of `Mapper.CreateMap`.